# Can't get updatable View in Linq and Sql 2005 to work.

Tags: sql-server, linq, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to do the following in the VS2008 Linq O/R designer, SQL 2005:

I have a table called `Entity` with an auto-incrementing primary key named `PKey`, and another field called `Parent`

I've made a View from this table, calling it vwEmployees, with a simple where clause.

Add both to O/R designer. in O/R, set the view's `PKey` to be `PrimaryKey=true` in properties in order to make the view updatable.

Added a one to many relation between them, from `PKey` in the table, to Parent in the view.

(A "parent" "entity" can have many "children" of the same record type)

Well, I get this error:

```
Incorrect AutoSync specification for member 'PKey'
```

I tried setting AutoSync to "Never", but still no dice.

If anyone has any clue as to why this occurs, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a Linq to SQL dbml file successfully using your examples using Visual Studio 2008:

[image]

I would check to make sure you have a correctly set the primary key in your Entity table database.  It could also simply be a bug in the 2005 version of the designer that has now been resolved in 2008.